# How To Retrieve and Display Records from an Access Database

Tags: ms-access

How can I retrieve and display a record from an Access Database.

I built a simple module and it works. I would like to access the database.

Comment: You're going to have to supply more information if you expect anyone to help.  If you've got a simple module to work, what's the problem?  Why can't you build the module you need?  What can't you do?  If you ask a specific question, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Do you know how to build a simple query using the access GUI?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in VBA or through the GUI?

Comment: This is what everyone is asking: are you using Access for the UI or some other programming environment?

Comment: Built a simple module where?